# Align spawned particle system

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am working on a game in which tanks can shoot at each other. I intend to spawn a spark particle system (particles emit to Z) when a bullet hits a surface. I want to align the Z axis of the newly spawned particle system to be

a) in a 90 degree angle to surface that has been hit
b) in a reflective angle from the original trajectory

I know that I can "fake it" by setting particle Z to World 90 degrees, however then it will do so on any angled surface, while I would like to have the particle system dynamically orient itself in a 90 degree angle away from the surface that has been hit/ or reflect into the direction away from the incoming bullet.

hope you can help me, getting quite frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do in that case after the instanciation of the transform is that :

```
sparksTransform.forward = hitPoint.normal;
```

And normally that's all there is.